# Adding an external message to php sendmail

Tags: php, email, sendmail

This has to be a simple and stupid question but cant seem to figure it out.
What I want to do is something like:

```
$message = include ('./myfile.php');
```

Obviously such does not work, but is there a way to accomplish this if that code worked.

Thanx

Here is full code (abbreviated):

```
        require_once ('./connect.php');
    $db = mysqli_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,"paratb_members");
    $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM board where accesskey = 'CHHXN5Jdwu'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    extract($row);
    $message = include './questions/resignation.php'; 

    $subject = "IAP Ballot";    
    $headers = "From: xxxx" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: xxxx" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $fromEmail = "xxxx";
    $fifth = "-f" . $fromEmail;
    $to      = "$fname $lname <$email>";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $fifth);    
    echo "Email sent to $lname: $email<br>";
```

Comment: Your question doesn't provide clear information about problem that you have faced. There is bit confusion what you want to achieve.

Comment: What's in `myfile.php` that you'd expect to end up in the variable?

Comment: _"Obviously such does not work"_ - Sure it will, as long as `myfile.php` has a return statement that returns what you want the variable to contain. Check out "Example #5" in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Actually it dosen't work. If myfile.php is actually the email message, the $message gets printed in the browser butnot in the email. Also tried using a plain include that contains the $message statement with same result. The myfile.php does contain variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can first read file & store data in variable which contain file's data then you can use that variable.

```
fopen("myfile.php", "r");
    $lines = file("myfile.php");
    $message = '';
    foreach($lines as $value) {
        $message .= $value." ";
    }
    echo ($message);
```

Comment: One problem though. If that file contains any PHP, it will never be executed, but literally be read as plain text. Also, if you just want the contents of a file, it would probably be easier to do the same by simply using `file_get_contents()` instead of iterating through the result like that. It would reduce the above code from 7 lines to 1.